# VS2022 solution opening by default in VS2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I have a Visual Studio solution whose projects I just upgraded to Toolset V143 which requires VS2022.

I saved all the project files AND the solution file.

The header of the solution file contains:

```
# Visual Studio Version 17
VisualStudioVersion = 17.5.33424.131
```

but when I double click the solution file it opens with VS2019 :(

What's the problem and how can I fix it please?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 3):

Screenshot:  Settings => Apps => Default Apps => Choose defaults by file type
[image: Settings/Apps/Default Apps/Choose defaults by file type]

Answer (score 2):

Well drats - .sln file was set to open by default with VS2019 - rather than the Visual Studio Version Selector :(

Now that's fixed ... it works as I expected - sorry for bandwith wastage.

D.

Comment: Might be useful to show how you found this association and fixed it ;)

Comment: It was suggested that I check what windows settings had as the default for opening .sln files: Windows Settings/Apps/Default Apps/Choose defaults by filetype. When I did I saw the were set to open with VS2019

Answer (score 0):

click the *.sln file and [image]
Word Count Patch Word Count Patch Word Count Patch